# GCP - MySQL - inserting data very slow from on-prm to vm as DB

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, networking, google-compute-engine

## Background

VM

- Machine Type = n2-custom-32-65536
- Boot disk = 120GB SSD
- Additional disk = 1080 SSD

I'm using Classic VPN to connect from on-prem to GCP and VM installed MySQL.

Here's the simple code

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="{VM internalIP}",
        user="{user}",
        password="{password}",
        database="{database}"
    )
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_insert_string = "INSERT INTO database(id, type, date, " \
                    "date_2, date_3, days) " \
                    "VALUES ('id','type','date','date_2','date_3','days')"
for i in range(1, 1000000):
  cursor.execute(sql_string)
  mydb.commit()
```

I ran the code from on-prem for five minutes and only inserted around 15,000 data into VM.

I also ran the code in the VM for five minutes and inserted 400,000 data into VM.

## Question

I would like to know how to speed up when I'm inserting data from on-prem into VM, and I know there's a networking problem here to make this different. But what should I do to insert data quickly without editing any above code?

Comment: You can try using `executemany` to pass a bunch of rows at once.

Comment: As well as using `executemany`, consider batching your commits, for example only for each 10000 rows (experiment to find the optimal value).

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Data from on-prem and vm for each server. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
TOP     1st page only
ulimit -a       for list of limits 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Ask GCP for assistance.

Comment: Executemany, with batches of 100 to 1000 will speed up the insert by a factor of 10.  (If you get significantly different results, please present your findings, together with more details.)