# Python - MySQLCursor.executemany() Method - performance

Tags: python, mysql, networking

Here's the original question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73173205/gcp-mysql-inserting-data-very-slow-from-on-prm-to-vm-as-db), and I just test with some conditions with `executemany`.

---

When I chose external IP to insert a bunch of rows, the `executemany` method seems still to send more packets and spend more time for passing the data. I also try this simple code.

```
 for j in range(0, 1000):
   cursor.execute(sql_insert_string)
 mydb.commit()
```

This is faster and fewer packets than using `executemany` when I pass data at external IP.

---

Also, when I chose internal IP to do the same thing, the `executemany` work well with less time and fewer packets.

I would like to know the deep reason to make this difference. Thank you all.

### Update

```
sql_insert_string_s = "INSERT INTO test.stress_testing (id, type, date, " \
                      "data_2, data_3, days) " \
                      "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
data = []
for i in range(0, 1):
    for j in range(0, 1000):
        data.append(('id', 'type', 'date', 'data_2', 'data_3', 'days'))
    mycursor.executemany(sql_insert_string_s, data)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Please show your code that uses `executemany`

Comment: You might want to execute each option multiple times to get a better feel for the timings.  And which connector package are you using?

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL for just, say, `range(0, 2)`.  We can see if `executemany` is doing what it is supposed to do.